# About express message. I can't get the template I made

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to get a response  like alert, as documented here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages

if default, I get like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XlA9.png

if I use a template I can not get anything https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG9eb.png

this is my folder structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2zHB.png

## in my app.js

```
    const express    = require('express');
    const path       = require('path');
    const mongoose   = require('mongoose');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const session    = require('express-session');
    
    const app = express();

    ...

    app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
    app.set('view engine','pug');
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    // set public folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


    ...


    app.use(session({
        secret:'keyboard cat',
        resave:true,
        saveUninitialized:true,
        cookie: { maxAge: 6000 }
    }));


   ...

    app.use(require('connect-flash')());
    app.use((req,res,next)=>{
        res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req,res);
        next();
    });

     ....

    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        req.flash('success','Cek lah');
    
        res.render('index',{
            title:'TinDev',
        });
    });

  ....
```

## in my app.pug

```
    .container
      //!= messages()
      != messages('message.pug',locals)
```

## in my message.pug

```
    .messages
      each type in Object.keys(messages)
        each message in messages[type]
          div(class="alert alert-" + type) #{ message }
```

I hope there is output like an alert,

is there anything that can explain to me why I did not get the output as desired?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to apply the flash-data to the render method. Please try this:

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.flash('success', 'Cek lah');

  res.render('index', {
    title: 'TinDev',
    messages: req.flash('success')
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure. You have to `include ./message` instead of `!= messages('message.pug',locals)` in the app.pug file.

Comment: I tried but had no effect. but I just got a solution for this typical by not using a template, but utilizing HTML that has been rendered by default only needs to be added CSS